# Depth values and FBO

Tags: c++, opengl

[image: a lovely depth texture]

This is the lovely image I keep seeing gDebugger as I attempt to implement shadow maps. For reference I'm using the tutorial at http://fabiensanglard.net/shadowmapping/index.php. I've tried a couple different things with varying results, mostly either an FBO that has flat depth values(no slight variance indicating weird depth ranges) or this awesome guy. I've tried a huge amount of different things but alas, sans complete FBO failure, I mostly come back to this. For reference, here is what gDebugger spits out as my actual depth buffer:

[image: depth]

So, with all that in mind, here's my code. Shader code is withheld because I have yet to get something in my FBO that's worth processing.

Here's how I initialize the FBO/Depth tex:

```
    int shadow_width = 1024;
    int shadow_height = 1024;

    // Try to use a texture depth component
    glGenTextures(1, &depth_tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_tex);

    // GL_LINEAR does not make sense for depth texture. However, next tutorial shows usage of GL_LINEAR and PCF
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // Remove artefact on the edges of the shadowmap
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP );

    // No need to force GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, drivers usually give you the max precision if available 
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 
        shadow_width, shadow_height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 
        GL_FLOAT, 0);
    // attach the texture to FBO depth attachment point 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // create a framebuffer object
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo_id);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_id);

    // Instruct openGL that we won't bind a color texture with the currently binded FBO
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_tex, 0);

    // switch back to window-system-provided framebuffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

And here's my render code:

```
    glLoadIdentity();
    float lpos[4] = {0,0,0,1};
    float lpos3[4] = {5000,-500,5000,1};

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo_id);
    glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE); 
    setup_mats(lpos[0],lpos[1],lpos[2],lpos3[0],lpos3[1],lpos3[2]);

    glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    mdlman.render_models(R_STENCIL);
    mdlman.render_model(R_STENCIL,1);
    set_tex_mat();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);

    glViewport( 0, 0, (GLsizei)800, (GLsizei)600 );
    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    this->r_cam->return_LookAt();
    gluPerspective(45,800/600,0.5f,2000.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixf(&r_cam->getProjectionMatrix()[0][0]);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadMatrixf(&r_cam->getViewMatrix()[0][0]);

    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    mdlman.render_models(R_NORM);
```

And here's how I draw objects for the FBO:

```
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,models.at(mdlid).t_buff);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,models.at(mdlid).i_buff);

        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,sizeof(vert),BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(GLfloat)*2));
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,sizeof(vert),BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(GLfloat)*5));         

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,(models.at(mdlid).f_index.size())*3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

Some closing notes: the depth buffer image from gDebugger IS from the lights POV. My camera is quaternion based and uses matrices aligned with OGL for it's lookAt function(which is used to translate to light position/view.) I can provide the code for that if need be. Everything else is pretty much carbon-copied from the tutorial to make sure that I'm not doing or setting up something stupid.

Comment: Whoooo! Could you please cut down your code to what you *suspect* is generating the errors (or the undesired behavior). That would GREATLY improve your question's readability and desirability to be answered.

Comment: I tried to reduce as much as possible; I'm really at a complete loss as to what could cause such an anomaly in my FBO - I'm not sure if it's in my matrices, rendering, or if it's a simple set up error. The grayscale image that I first posted really doesn't give me an idea of where it could be going wrong(or moreover, I don't understand what is going wrong.)

Comment: @Mark I think this is the best way. I really hate when people think that some piece of code is wrong post only that and it tuns out that it is totally irrelevant.

Comment: What does `mdlman.render_models(R_STENCIL);   mdlman.render_model(R_STENCIL,1);` do instead of  `mdlman.render_models(R_NORM);`?

Comment: Can you check the result of glCheckFramebufferStatus, just in case you may have a dud FBO? (See the tutorial code on how to do that.)

Comment: Also, why don't you do a normal render with the projection and model view matrices setup for the FBO render (From the lights perspective.). Maybe your light is right in or in front of the object.

Comment: R_STENCIL is my incorrectly labeled enum for making the render process ignore using textures and shaders - it calls nothing but what's needed for DrawElements to work. R_NORM is "render normal" so that's the pass where textures are drawn and the proper shader is used. It's all a little hacked together at the moment but I'm still figuring out certain aspects of shaders. glCheckFramebufferStatus() comes back with Framebuffer Complete. The depth render I posted is essentially the normal render from the light - I had lights/textures disabled when I posted.

Comment: Welp, got it figured out; turns out I wasn't unlocking my camera so it wasn't actually doing any matrix math. Doh!